# skip row if user_id contains a specific code

Tags: mysql

I have these rows

```
 user_id   code
    1      9103 
    1      9103 
    1      9001
    2      9103
    3      9103
    3      9104
    4      9103
    4      9103
    4      9001
```

I want to get only id that not contains 9001, then only 2 and 3
I try with Distinct But I without lucky

```
Select distinct v.code, user_id from mytable as v
    where v.code not in ( Select v2.code from mytable as v2
    where v2.code=9001)
```

Comment: Go on. Try something. Still struggling? See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 4):

Group by the user and then take only those groups having no record of the condition

```
select user_id
from your_table
group by user_id
having sum(code = 9001) = 0
```

Comment: SQL at its best.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple methods to get the results you need.

**NOT EXISTS (ALL DBMS)**

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM 
 Table1
WHERE
 NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 
   1
  FROM 
   Table1
  WHERE 
   code = 9001
)
```

**NOT IN (ALL DBMS)**

```
SELECT
 DISTINCT 
  Table1.user_id
FROM 
 Table1 
WHERE
 user_id NOT IN (

  SELECT
   user_id
  FROM 
   Table1
  WHERE
   code = 9001

)
```

**RIGHT JOIN / LEFT JOIN (ALL DBMS but for example SQLite does not support RIGHT JOIN)**

```
SELECT 
 DISTINCT
  Table1.user_id
FROM (
  SELECT
   user_id
  FROM 
   Table1
  WHERE
   code = 9001
) AS Table1_filter
RIGHT JOIN 
 Table1
ON
 Table1_filter.user_id = Table1.user_id
WHERE
 Table1_filter.user_id IS NULL

;

SELECT 
  DISTINCT
    Table1.user_id
FROM 
 Table1 
LEFT JOIN  (
  SELECT
   user_id
  FROM 
   Table1
  WHERE
   code = 9001
) AS Table1_filter
ON
 Table1_filter.user_id = Table1.user_id 
WHERE
 Table1_filter.user_id IS NULL
;
```

**Conditional SUM (@juergen d answer) (ALL DBMS)**

```
SELECT 
 Table1.user_id
FROM 
 Table1
GROUP BY 
 Table1.user_id
HAVING 
 SUM(Table1.code = 9001) = 0
```

**Variation on (@juergen d answer) with `GROUP_CONCAT` (MySQL and SQLite only)**

Also possible with

`... HAVING FIND_IN_SET('9001', GROUP_CONCAT(Table1.code)) = 0` (MySQL Only)

```
SELECT 
 Table1.user_id
FROM 
 Table1
GROUP BY 
  Table1.user_id
HAVING   
  GROUP_CONCAT(Table1.code) NOT LIKE '%9001%'
```

p.s `GROUP_CONCAT(Table1.code) NOT LIKE '%9001%'` might also select false positives depending on the data used. Using `FIND_IN_SET('9001', GROUP_CONCAT(Table1.code)) = 0` is more safe option to use.

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc6f6b/34